# Convert data between databases with different schemes and value codings

Tags: python, json, data-conversion

As part of my job I am meant to write a script to convert data from an available database here on-site to an external database for publication which is similar but far less detailed. I want to achieve this in Python.

Some columns can just be converted by copying their content changing the coding, i.e. `2212` in the original database becomes `2` in the external database in column `X`. To achieve this I wrote the codings in JSON, e.g.

```json
{
    "2212": 2,
    "2213": 1,
    "2214": 2,
    ...
}
```

This leads to some repetition as you can see but since lists cannot be keys in JSON I don't see a better way to it (which is simple and clean; sure I could have the right hand side as a key but then instead of `jsonParsedDict["2212"]` I would have to go through all the keys `1, 2, ...` and find my original key on the right hand side.)

Where it gets ugly (in my opinion) is when information from multiple columns in the original database need to be combined to get the new column. Right now I just wrote a Python function doing a lot of `if` checks. It works and I will finish the job this way but it just seems aesthetically wrong and I want to learn more about Python's possibilities in that task.

Imagine for example I have two columns in the original database `X` and `Y` and then based on values in `X` I either do nothing (for values that are not coded in the external database), return a value directly or I return a result based on what value `Y` has in the same row. Right now this leads to quite some `if` statements. My other idea was to have stacked entries in the JSON file, e.g.

```json
{
    "X":
    {
        "2211": 1,
        "2212": null,
        "2213": 
        {
            "Y":
            {
                "3112": 1
                "3212": 2
            }
        }
        "2214": 
        {
            "Y":
            {
                "3112": 2
                "3212": 1
            }
        }
        "2215": 
        {
            "Y":
            {
                "3112": 1
                "3212": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this approach really blows up the JSON file and repetitions get even more painful. Alas I cannot think of any other way to code these kind of conditions, apart from `if` in the code.

Is this a feasible way to do it or is there a better solutions? It would be great if I could specify the variables and associated variables, which are part of the decision process, only in the JSON file. I want to abstract the conversion process such that it is mostly steered by these JSON files and the Python code is quite general. If there is a better format for this than JSON then suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use `(x, y)` tuples as keys? Like `{(2211, 3112):(1,1), (2214,3112):2,(2212,None):(None,None),...}`

Comment: As far as I know the keys in a JSON file always need to be strings. How would I code tuples in that case?

Comment: Sorry, you can use `str((2211, 3112))`, use double parenthesis. To turn back to a tuple from string you could use `from ast import literal_eval` and then `literal_eval(str((2211,3112)))` will convert correctly back to a tuple

Comment: This is definitely intriguing but then I would have to spell out every tuple combination there is or still do some testing on the Python side. Imagine the first case: if `X` is `2211` then `Y` does not play any role, I thus would have to code `{"(2211, 3112)": 1, "(2211, 3212)": 1}`. This is exactly the kind of verbosity I am trying to avoid. I basically want my code in a clean way recognize if there is a second variable evolved and then look at the values of that variable (without me having to state in the code which variable that is. Hence the variable name in my original example).